# csv python file not saving in individual line

Tags: python, csv, url, beautifulsoup

1. The code is working but the URLs saved are being saved in a single line rather than a different line.

   ```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import urllib2
   import requests
   import csv
   import re

   page=requests.get("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_values.htm")

   data=BeautifulSoup(page.content)

   csv1=open("123.csv","wb+")

   for link in data.find_all('a'):
       print(link.get('href'))
       csv1.write(link.get('href'))



   csv1.close()
   ```
2. Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you already import the csv module, maybe you can try using it.

Comment: the `write` does not write a _newline_ character at the end by default like the `print` does. you have to add it yourself

Comment: ok....but may I ask how?

Comment: Ofc you may. This would be one way to do it: `csv1.write(link.get('href') + '\n')`. Note that this will produce an empty line at the end of your file.

Comment: Side-note: What you're writing is technically a CSV-like format, but only in the sense that there is a single field per record, so no commas were needed in the first place. Even so, it could go wrong (without using `csv` module, it won't quote fields with embedded commas or newlines), so if you want to write true CSV, you need to wrap `csv1` in a `csv.writer` object. You also should drop the `+` from your `open` mode string, unless you have some reason you'll need to rewind and reread what you've written in the same process.

Comment: Thank you so very much for the help. You're a life saver

Comment: An alternative way to write the newlines would be to just use `print` mind you. I prefer the Py3 `print` function over the Py2 `print` statement (you can get the Py3 version in Py2 by making the first line in your file `from __future__ import print_function`), and for correctness, the file should be opened with mode `"w"` (`print` is text oriented), but aside from that, you'd just change `csv1.write(link.get('href'))` to `print(link.get('href'), file=csv1)` and `print` handles adding the newline (and writes `\r\n` correctly on Windows, where binary mode `write` of `\n` would not include `\r`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger it is a great explanation... I didn't get much but thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just `csv1.write`, use `csv.writer` modules

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import requests
import csv
import re

page=requests.get("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_values.htm")

data=BeautifulSoup(page.content)

csv1=open("123.csv","wb+")
csv1writer = csv.writer(csv1)

for link in data.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
    csv1writer.writerow([link.get('href')])

csv1.close()
```